# Danger of opening and terminating subprocess in a forever loop

Tags: python, loops, subprocess, terminate

Are there any possible danger posed by opening and terminating subprocesses in a forever loop? Like garbage accumulation, overflow, etc?

```
import subprocess
import time

while True: 

    a = subprocess.Popen(["./hello_video.bin", "/home/pi/test_plane.m4v"])
    time.sleep(10)
    a.terminate();

    b = subprocess.Popen(["./hello_video.bin", "/home/pi/test_girl.m4v"])
    time.sleep(10)
    b.terminate();
```

Comment: What is the purpose of your program? There might be a better way of doing things.

Comment: I have several videos. Each video corresponds to  a keyboard input. A video should play in a seamless looping way (using hello_video.bin) unless I press another key input. Right after I press a key input, the current video should disappear and the new corresponding video should display on the screen. It would be nice if I can pause the inactive video (subprocess) instead of killing it.

Answer (score 2):

Yes. On UNIX/Posix, it sends a SIGTERM signal to the process. Then process should be terminated, but in some cases it won't. It is not guaranteed that the process will be already terminated when Popen.terminate() returns (for example, if the process is waiting for I/O or in an uninterruptable sleep). Child process can ignore SIGTERM easily. Even if it does not ignore SIGTERM, it might become a zombie. If you really need to terminate processes in an infinite loop, you should check if the process was really terminated. Look at the psutil module too.

UPDATE: Change from SIGKILL to SIGTERM, thanks   J.F. Sebastian

Comment: 1. [SIGKILL always works](http://unix.stackexchange.com/q/5642/1321). 2. `Popen.terminate()` generates `SIGTERM` signal (different from `SIGKILL`). `SIGTERM` *can* be ignored.

Comment: Yes, sorry. You are right. Another reason why he should check if the process has really terminated or not.

Comment: 0. `.terminate()` returns at once. It does not wait for any child state (sleep or no sleep). It does not communicate with the child directly. SIGTERM is asynchronous. 1. Zombie by definition is dead i.e., if the process is alive (if it hasn't been terminated on SIGTERM in this case) then it can't be a zombie. 2. `subprocess` module keeps track of active children and reaps zombies in `Popen()` i.e., the code in the question won't create many zombies even if OP never calls `.wait()` (or equivalent)

Comment: Yes, the child process can simply ignore SIGTERM and then it won't be a zombie. But it is possible that it will be. (Just not likely).